# PHP Execute Class On Web Server Request

Tags: php, apache

I have a simple question.

Say I have the following:

```
<?php
 echo "Test";

?>
```

That will echo out "Test".

But How do I get echo to execute when the file is called by a web server I have:

```
<?php

class className{
   echo "Test";

}
```

Comment: Put echo in a method, instantiate this class and call the method.

Comment: I am doing: $newObject = new ClassName(); newObject->callFunction(); above my class code and it isn't working.

Comment: To say what's wrong let's see code with class, calling its method and the request to server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do that in this way. Create a `function` inside the `class` and `echo "Test"` inside that function

```
<?php
    class className{
        function __construct(){
            $this->init();
        }

        function init(){                
            echo "Test";
        }
    }

    $obj = new className();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, your answer may be useful to someone.
I was just making a really stupid mistake ..